# Fetch Value from Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a requirement to fetch values from

```
Map<Object1, Object2>() objectMap= new HashMap<Object1, Object2>();
Object1 obj1 = new Object1();
Object2 obj2 = new Object2();

//Object1 class:
public class Object1{
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String number;

//along with getters and setters
}

//Object2 class:
public class Object2{
   private String value1; 
   private String value2;

//along with getters and settersenter code here
}

objectMap.put(obj1, obj2);
Object1 obj3 = new Object1();
```

`obj3` has values same as `obj1`, i.e all the fields, name, value and number as the same for `obj3`.

I need to fetch value of map using `obj3` if `obj1` equals `obj3`. How do I check `obj1` equals to `obj3` and then how do I fetch map value using `obj3`?

Comment: `Object1 obj1 = new Object1();` `Object1 obj3 = new Object1();`. Here, `obj1` and `obj3` are not `equal` unless you implement `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you start like this

```
objectMap.put(obj1, obj2);
```

Now in your `Map` you have a single key/value pair.  If you then call

```
objectMap.get(obj1);
```

you will get `obj2` back.  This is because the object you are using for the lookup has the same `hashCode` and is 'equal()' to the object used for the `put`.

If you then do this

```
objectMap.get(obj3);
```

you will get `obj2` back.  This is again because the object you are using for the lookup has the same `hashCode` and is 'equal()' to the object used for the `put`.

so.

If you do:

```
Object1 o1 = null;
if (obj1.equals(obj3) { 
  o1 = objectMap.get(obj1);
}
```

The you will retrieve the value you want from the map only if the keys are equal.  Obviously the `if` statement is completely redundant, it is there to prove the point of the keys being equal in order for this to work.  Obviously your class `Object1` needs `equals` and `hashcode` implemented for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<K,V> map=new Hash Map<K,V>();
```

for(Map.Entry m= map.entry Set())

{

m.put(object 1);
   m.put(object 2);

```
}
```

Comment: use for this approach java 8 because  comparable and comparator  are    implicitly  implemented for Map.@user